# catching java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

I'm new in Java. Can anyone help me with explanation, why the catch is not catching the MyException (which extends ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)? 
My example:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            doTest();
        }
        catch(MyException me){
            System.out.println("MyException is here");
        }
    }

    static void doTest() throws MyException{
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[10] = 1000;

    }


}
class MyException extends ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    public MyException(String msg){
     super(msg);
    }
}
```

The result is: 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10         at TestClass.doTest(TestClass.java:14)         at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:5)"

Why is not "MyException is here"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the subtype-supertype-relationship.

The code as it is throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but not a `MyException`. Catching the latter will not work because an AIOOBE *is not a* ME. Your ME is a subtype of AIOOBE.

On the other hand, an AIOOBE has a supertype: `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. If you have a catch clause for this one, you will get the desired behavior because an AIOOBE *is a* IOOBE.

Or you could simply throw your ME yourself: `throw new MyException(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Your method actually throws only `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You catch `MyException` but that is not what is being thrown, so the `catch` clause has no effect.

If you wanted to throw `MyException` you would have to modify the method to catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and throw `MyException` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your doTest method does not throw your custom exception. To throw an exception use

```
throw new MyException("your message");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it throw the exception when accessing the 10th element in the array (which doesn't exist)?

Comment: Accessing an invalid index throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You can't make it throw any other exception type.

Comment: But doTest throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Why it is not catch?

Comment: @EgorTitov Because you don't have a catch clause for an AIOOBE or any _supertype_ of it.